# Once again about CALayers and ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, calayer

In my project I work with CAlayers. ARC is enabled. In `viewDidLoad` I'm implementing all my layers and their s contents:

```
CALayer *tipLayer = [CALayer layer];
tipLayer.frame = CGRectMake(20, 510, 220, 30);
tipLayer.contents = (__bridge id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"tipBackground.png"].CGImage;
[tipLayer setOpacity:0.7f];
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:tipLayer];
```

This is one of my layers. After implementation my app's memory grow from 9Mb to 12Mb. But after `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` memory stay with value 12Mb.
I already tried `-[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]` instead `[UIImage imageNamed:]` but it doesn't work. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked that the view controller is deallocated, same for the view?

Comment: @Wain Yes, controller is deallocated, but memory is not released.